# How to say "Kafkaesque" in Russian?

Tags: лексикон, перевод, одним-словом

What is the best way to convey the meaning of the English word "Kafkaesque" in Russian as succinctly and correctly as possible? I'm interested in both noun and adjective versions.

I understand "Kafkaesque" as something that is absurd, distorted and causes the feel of existential angst.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The corpus knows the noun *кафкианство*:

> - Экая гоголиана, устало думал Миша Белосельско-Белозерский, экое утомительное кафкианство, экая мамлеевщина, экий сорокинизм! *[Василий Аксенов. Негатив положительного героя (1996)]*

and the adjective *кафкианский*:

> - Газет я не читала, но стопка на тумбочке источала ужас. Сегодня я бы сказала ― кафкианский ужас. Одно воспоминание тех лет было настолько пронзительным, что осталось частью моей биографии. *[Р. М. Фрумкина. О нас – наискосок (1995)]*

Comment: мы рождены, чтоб Кафку сделать былью )))